# Issue with Netsuite Integration in Sandbox when posting to restlet

Tags: integration, netsuite, httpresponse, content-type

Using Postman, I'm testing an http post to a rest url created in netsuite. everything works perfectly in the netsuite environment it was originally created in but when the resources were bundled and tested in sandbox, the post call is authorized but it's like the url is not being seen. The response status is "200 OK" but nothing is returning or processing and I'm not getting any error or messages on either side. The only thing I've noticed is Content-type is changed to "text/html; charset=utf-8" in my header. I know the integration application is working because I accidentally used the wrong rest url and the failure was logged in the integration log.

For my header looks like the following example:

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:OAuth 
  realm="123456",
  oauth_consumer_key="*******************************************",
  oauth_token="**************************************************",
  oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
  oauth_timestamp="1234567890",
  oauth_nonce="aB1cdE2FghI",oauth_version="1.0",
  oauth_signature="**************************"
```

The requestbody is formated as:

```
{

 "datakey1": "value 1",
 "datakey2": "value 2",
 "datakey3": "value 3",
 .......

}
```

I'm not sure if it is a permission issue or what, I've tried everything: created new scripts, rebuilt the resources in sandbox, and other things but nothing works. I'm stomped

The following header is what's returned:

```
Cache-Control →No-Cache
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Length →0
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Thu, 17 Aug 2017 16:00:16 GMT
Edge-Control →no-store
Expires →0
Keep-Alive →timeout=10, max=996
NS_RTIMER_COMPOSITE →.........
```

EDITED:

Figured out the answer!!!

Once I set the Script Deployment Status to "Released" in both environments everything worked as expected

In conjunction, if using SuiteScript 2.0, add the NModuleScope to the entry tag. The default is 'SameAccount' but that may cause issues once installed in another account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your POST URL is referencing the system.sandbox url for the REST endpoint. Also make sure that the "realm" parameter in the OAuth header is your Sandbox account ID. If neither of those are the issue, I would try and redo the token setup in Sandbox. Create a new Integration Record, and a new User Access Token. Last thing to check is to make sure the Role being used for the Access Token is not setup as "Web Services Only". Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Todd Grimm! I just checked and tried each of these steps and still no luck